# How to create a new column through a specific condition?

Tags: python, algorithm, conditional-statements, calculated-columns

I have a column like this:

```
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
1
0
0
```

and need as result:

```
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

A method/algorithm that divides into ranks from 1 to 1 and gives them successively values.
Any idea?

Comment: try this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html

Comment: is there a guaranteed `1` at index `0`?

Comment: @user1984 yes, 1 at index 0

Comment: @VictorSaraivaRocha thanks, taking a look

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are after, but `cumsum()` in either numpy or pandas would produce such a result. E.g. `np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]).cumsum()`.

Comment: A column of *what*? If you are using a third-party module, please mention it in your question and tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the list and use a counter to update the column value, and increment it everytime you find the number 1.

```
def rank(lst):
    counter = 0
    for i, column in enumerate(lst):
        if column == 1:
            counter+=1
        lst[i] = counter
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def fill_arr(arr): 
    curr = 1 
    for i in range(1, len(arr)): 
        arr[i] = curr  
        if i < len(arr)-1 and arr[i+1] == 1: 
            curr += 1 
    return arr
```

A quick test

```
arr = [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0]                                                                                 
fill_arr(arr)                                                                                                 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

The idea is as follows:

1. keep track of the number of `1`s we encounter it `curr` by looking ahead and increment it as we see new `1`s.
2. set the elements at the current index to `curr`.
3. we start at index `1` since we know that there is a one at index zero. This helps us reduce edge cases and make the algorithm easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is usually called the **cumulated sums**; or as a verb, you're looking to **increasingly accumulate** the values in the list.

### For a python list:

```py
import itertools

l1 = [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0]

l2 = list(itertools.accumulate(l1))

print(l2)
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

### For a numpy array:

```py
import numpy

a1 = numpy.array([1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0])

a2 = a1.cumsum()

print(a2)
# [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3]
```

### For a column in a pandas dataframe:

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'col1': [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0]})
df['col2'] = df['col1'].cumsum()

print(df)
#     col1  col2
# 0      1     1
# 1      0     1
# 2      0     1
# 3      0     1
# 4      1     2
# 5      0     2
# 6      0     2
# 7      0     2
# 8      1     3
# 9      0     3
# 10     0     3
```

### Documentation:

- [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate);
- [numpy.cumsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html);
- [numpy.ndarray.cumsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.cumsum.html);
- [pandas.DataFrame.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html);
- [pandas.Series.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html).